# Searchcriteria with null expression

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to use Specification interface. So far so good but now I would like to use an optional search criteria.
In the code below if customerId(Long) is null I would like to get all the customers from db and if not only the the customer with the specific Id. Now only works the second part.
Is it possible to get all the customers if the given Id is null?
Thanks in advance!

```
Specification<Order> customer = (root, query, cb) -> {return cb.equal(root.get("customerId"), customerId);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create a condition to return an empty (default) CriteriaBuilder on null `customerId`:

```
 Specification<Order> customer = (root, query, cb) -> {
     if(customerId == null){
       return cb; // return empty CriteriaBuilder
     }
     return cb.equal(root.get("customerId"), customerId);
 };
```